# How to resize the app after making it from python?

Tags: python, resize, pyinstaller

Recently, I made up a calculator app with Python Tkinter. And I used PyInstaller to make it as an app(.exe file). After making it as an app, I cannot resize the app. But, when I run my python code it perfectly resize, whereas in the app it doesn't resize. Please help me someone!!!I'm a newbie to programming

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `resizable()` method should be able to help you:

```
window = Tk()
window.resizable(True, True)
```

Read more here: https://www.kite.com/python/docs/tkinter.Tk.resizable